# Setting table element to width 0

Tags: html, css

I have a the following HTML table:

[image: 1]

This is the actual markup:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7">
                <h2>Title</h2>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Row</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The h2 element (red box) doesn't quite line up in the middle of the headers (green line) because of the row title element (orange circle).

Setting the width of the row title element to 0 doesn't quite work, but that's what I'm trying to do in principal. Using a left/right margin on the title won't work because the actual row title has varying widths.

---

**EDIT:** Using `<td><td colspan="6">` doesn't entirely solve the problem either. When stacking multiple of these tables, their titles don't line up horizontally. Notice that the number of columns and column width vary from table to table.

[image: 2]

Comment: Please add your code as well.

Comment: See my edit @CodeRomeos

Comment: Do you want to stack tables? Can you not just stack tbody?

Comment: Yes, each table has a unique title and thead, in addition to a varying number of columns @Chris

Comment: I don't think you can do this without changing html. However, if you can keep 1 table, you can do this. http://jsfiddle.net/ppj08xxh/3/ is this okay?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because not every table will have 6 columns @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take those `th` out-of-flow:

```css
body {
  padding: 0 100px;  /* Some margin to prevent th from being pushed too much */
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;    /* Center horizontally */
  position: relative;/* Containing block for the th */
}
tr > th:first-child {
  position: absolute;/* Out of flow */
  right: 100%;       /* Push it to the left of the table */
  width: 100px;      /* Some width */
  text-align: right; /* Align inner content to the right */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th colspan="6"><h2>Title</h2></th></tr>
    <tr><th></th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Row</th><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th colspan="6"><h2>Title</h2></th></tr>
    <tr><th></th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Another Row</th><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like the Bootstrap grid system?
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't align because the 7-column wide `th` starts from the left and stretches out 7 columns which is the entire width of the table. You need it to be in the middle of the 6. So try this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="6">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Row</th>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

That will put an empty `th` tag on the left, followed by a 6-column wide `th` tag. That will center your title.

**EDIT:** Here are some fiddles:

As you had it: http://jsfiddle.net/ppj08xxh/

As I suggested above: http://jsfiddle.net/ppj08xxh/2

Comparing the two, I cannot see the shift you mentioned.

Comment: This fixes the title, but shifts the entire table over relative to the page

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I shouldn't shift anything, and I can't see such change. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I think this is the good answer. OP must explain better what you need. Vote up

Comment: My bad for the confusion. See my edit for more explanation

Comment: @RichardWallace I'm afraid I don't think there is a solution for what you want. You want the title to align in the center of X columns, but X varies from table to table and the text in the first cell varies too. I think the only solution here is to put your title outside of the table. Is that acceptable?